# Rails - Linkedin Auth: Not found. Authentication passthru

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

Hi have an application with Linkedin Authentication that used to work fine. Today I got complains from user saying they see: `Not found. Authentication passthru.` when clicking on login with Linkedin. it takes them to the page: `http://XXXXX/users/auth/linkedin?locale=en`

When i check in the logs I get :

```
Started GET "/users/auth/linkedin?locale=en" for ::1 at 2021-07-12 18:04:13 +0800
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#passthru as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"en"}
  Rendering text template
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

My controller looks like:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def linkedin

    @user = User.connect_to_linkedin(request.env["omniauth.auth"],current_user)
    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.linkedin_uid"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.failure"

    end
  end
```

I have the following in my model:

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:linkedin

```
             user_linkedin_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /users/auth/linkedin(.:format)                                                omniauth_callbacks#passthru
              user_linkedin_omniauth_callback GET|POST /users/auth/linkedin/callback(.:format)                                       omniauth_callbacks#linkedin
```

When I add the `POST` method to the link_to, i get the following:

```
Started POST "/users/auth/linkedin?locale=en" for ::1 at 2021-07-12 21:56:18 +0800
D, [2021-07-12T21:56:18.416654 #65475] DEBUG -- omniauth: (linkedin) Request phase initiated.
W, [2021-07-12T21:56:18.417955 #65475]  WARN -- omniauth: Attack prevented by OmniAuth::AuthenticityTokenProtection
E, [2021-07-12T21:56:18.418089 #65475] ERROR -- omniauth: (linkedin) Authentication failure! authenticity_error: OmniAuth::AuthenticityError, Forbidden
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
```

And other stuff

Do you see what could be teh reason behind this sudden problem please?
I did a Bundle Update few days ago and a lot of errors started showing up.

None of what i saw so far could help.

Comment: Where does the 404 error come from?

Comment: Have you tried hitting the endpoint with a POST request instead of GET? If you recently updated, it may be that you now need to POST (see https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/issues/960 - and there is also this gem to help out https://github.com/cookpad/omniauth-rails_csrf_protection)

Comment: I do not know, i have never had any problem with this tool. I am trying to locate the possible cause.

Comment: @johansenja, i added the gem and modified the link_to, so i managed to get the user to Linkedin authentication page, but on the way back to my app, it takes teh user to the devise sign_in page and shows:
ERROR -- omniauth: (linkedin) Authentication failure! csrf_detected: OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected

Comment: Are you including a CSRF token in the request? You can do something like <%= button_to "Continue with LinkedIn", user_linkedin_omniauth_authorize_path, method: :post %> which will turn your button into a form with the necessary token

Comment: @johansenja, i get the following : WARN -- omniauth: Attack prevented by OmniAuth::AuthenticityTokenProtection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this was because of CSRF protection enabled by default in OmniAuth 2 and above, and GET requests no longer supported like the one you are trying.

I was able to fix it with two things:

1. Add `omniauth-rails_csrf_protection` gem: https://github.com/cookpad/omniauth-rails_csrf_protection
2. Update your config/initializers/omniauth.rb to include:

```
OmniAuth.config.allowed_request_methods = [:get, :post]
```

Answer (score 1):

In `application.rb` whats's your `config.load_defaults` set to? I've been having issues myself if this is set to `6.1`. `6.0` works fine. Its some issue related to cookie SameSite settings (needs to be lax for localhost, and none+secure for live on the web usually - I could be wrong).
And also yes, check you're doing a POST to your sign in endpoint with CSRF checking in place.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same errors today. The problem may related to the version of OmniAuth.
When you use omniauth > 2.0, you should explicit the version of omniauth-rails_csrf_protection to 1.0

reference: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Upgrading-to-2.0#rails

Gemfile

```
gem 'omniauth-linkedin-oauth2', '~> 1.0'
gem 'omniauth-rails_csrf_protection', '~> 1.0'
part of my Gemfile.lock
```

part of my Gemfile.lock

```
    oauth2 (2.0.6)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 3.0)
      jwt (>= 1.0, < 3.0)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (>= 1.2, < 3)
      rash_alt (>= 0.4, < 1)
      version_gem (~> 1.1)
    omniauth (2.1.0)
      hashie (>= 3.4.6)
      rack (>= 2.2.3)
      rack-protection
    omniauth-linkedin-oauth2 (1.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.8.0)
      oauth2 (>= 1.4, < 3)
      omniauth (~> 2.0)
    omniauth-rails_csrf_protection (1.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.2)
      omniauth (~> 2.0)
```